# Switching currently displayed form (winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms

If I'm going about things COMPLETELY wrong here please tell me the better way to do it. Also sorry for any bad formatting / bad question wording; I haven't really used SO before.

I'm making a maths app which will draw polygons and other shapes and work out the area.
I have a menustrip where you can choose the shape to draw:

[image] 
I want to make it so when you click one of the buttons (polygon/circle) it will take you to the associated form (I will post the forms below): 
[image] 
I'm trying to control the currently displayed form with a C# class i've made called "MenuManager.cs" however it's giving me an error:

> System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'MathsApp.PolygonCalculator' threw an exception.' ArgumentException: Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'

. I will post the code below:

```cs
    public class MenuManager
    {
        /* Reference to forms */
        PolygonCalculator polygonCalculator = new PolygonCalculator();
        CircleCalculator circleCalculator = new CircleCalculator();
        /* I believe this is causing the errors. */

        public void MenuClickPolygon(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            polygonCalculator.Show();
        }

        public void MenuClickCircle(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            circleCalculator.Show();
        }

    }
```

This is how i'm accessing the MenuManager class and trying to change the displayed form:

```cs
this.Menu = new MainMenu();
MenuItem item = new MenuItem("Shapes");
this.Menu.MenuItems.Add(item);
item.MenuItems.Add("Polygon", new EventHandler(menuManager.MenuClickPolygon));
item.MenuItems.Add("Circle", new EventHandler(menuManager.MenuClickCircle));
```

```
    public partial class PolygonCalculator : Form
    {
        public static Color penColour = Color.Black;
        public static Random rnd = new Random();
        public static MenuManager menuManager = new MenuManager();

        public PolygonCalculator()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InstantiateMenu();
        }

        public void InstantiateMenu()
        {
            this.Menu = new MainMenu();
            MenuItem item = new MenuItem("Shapes");
            this.Menu.MenuItems.Add(item);
            item.MenuItems.Add("Polygon", new EventHandler(menuManager.MenuClickPolygon));
            item.MenuItems.Add("Circle", new EventHandler(menuManager.MenuClickCircle));
        }
```

```
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new PolygonCalculator());
        }
```

Comment: System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'MathsApp.PolygonCalculator' threw an exception.'

ArgumentException: Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'.

Comment: At what line ? Does it not say where it threw the exception, or which element caused it ?

Comment: In program.cs, On this line:
`Application.Run(new PolygonCalculator());`

Comment: Well there's your error.Can you please provide the code for the `PolygonCalculator` class?Also provide the code for the main method where you call `Application.Run` so people can understand the problem.

Comment: Yes, I'll make an edit now. I will omit some of the methods because they're not relevent (they calculate verticies, XY coords etc..)

Comment: Can you also add the `Program.Main` code?

Comment: How is your  `MenuManager.MenuClickPolygon` called since it is not a `Form` (it does not extend it) ?

Comment: Updated. Also, the MenuClickPolygon is called when you click the menustrip item.

Comment: You have PolygonCalculator creating a new MenuManager, which creates a new PolygonCalculator...

Comment: @LarsTech how can I make the MenuManager use the already instantiated PolygonCalcular instance?

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian Any tips?

Comment: Why would the PolygonCalculator have a menu item to open a PolygonCalculator?

Comment: So as @LarsTech asked there are  some issues.First your MenuManager is not a `Form` so i do not see how its delegate will be called.You should make it a form.Inside it you can instantiate your children and pass the parent in their constructor:  `this.polygonCalc=new PolygonCalculator(this)`